# How to get rid of space at the end of output?

Tags: java, arrays, syntax, output

My code checks if a certain number of user inputted string have any repeated characters. For example, if I input the strings "google" "paper" and "water", the code returns "paper" and "water"; because "google" has two Os.

I have the code part down, but when printing, a space appears after the very last string that is output and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

class words{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number or words: ");
        String[] words = new String[sc.nextInt()];
        System.out.print("Enter the strings: ");
        boolean truth = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            words[i] = sc.next();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
            int j;
            for(j=1;j<words[i].length();j++) {
                if(words[i].charAt(j) == words[i].charAt(j-1)){
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(j==words[i].length()){
                truth = true;
                System.out.print(words[i]+" ");
            }
        }
        if(!truth){
            System.out.println("NONE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Functions Make Logic Readable

Move the logic to check for repeating characters into a function; I would take advantage of [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) and the shorter array syntax. Like,

```
private static boolean repeatedChars(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        return false;
    }
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length - 1; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == chars[i + 1]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then, you can use a lambda to filter your `words` based on them not having repeated characters and collect with [`Collectors.joining(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) like

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the number or words: ");
String[] words = new String[sc.nextInt()];
System.out.print("Enter the strings: ");

for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = sc.next();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(words).filter(s -> !repeatedChars(s))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
```

**And**, if you need to display the `NONE` message you might re-use the `Predicate<String>` like

```
Predicate<String> pred = s -> !repeatedChars(s);
if (Arrays.stream(words).anyMatch(pred)) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(words).filter(pred).collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
} else {
    System.out.println("NONE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy workaround for your problem. Instead of printing every word immediately if it does not have any continuous repetition, add it to a String variable with space at the end so that each word is separated by a space. After you run through your loop, you check if your flag is false and print NONE if it is false. If it is true, however, print the result string where you added everything with a .trim() at the end.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = sc.next();
}
String result = ""; /*This is the string that holds all the strings that you need to print.*/

for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
    int j;
    for(j=1;j<words[i].length();j++) {
        if(words[i].charAt(j) == words[i].charAt(j-1)){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(j==words[i].length()){
        truth = true;
        result  = result + (words[i]+" ");
    }
}
if(!truth){
    System.out.println("NONE");
}
else{
    System.out.println(result.trim()); /*The trim function removes any redundant space in the beginning and the end of the string.*/
}
```

Of-course doing it this way will waste a lot of Heap Memory but I guess this is for a small learning project. However, do look into [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) on how to use it to avoid creating a lot of memory in the Heap!